# How to use a python library from a ruby codebase?

Tags: python, ruby, pyinstaller, ffi

Planning to use cookiecutter package(written in python) in a Thor CLI (written in ruby) to generate code templates for multiple languages, can anyone please suggest how to go about using a python lib in a ruby codebase?

I could come up with these approaches but not sure if they'll work.

1. Make a python executable for cookiecutter using pyinstaller and integrate it in the CLI to create templates.
2. Use any FFI tool(like rubypython) in the cli to call cookiecutter's python package.
3. Make a separate ruby gem with native extensions which call Python bindings of cookiecutter in C.

Not sure if the above approaches are the correct way. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: My intuitive approach would have been solution (1), since I did not know that _rubypython_ exists, so it could be fun to try out. (3) sounds ambitious to me. A different approach would be to look at the sourcecode of _cookiecutter_ and rewrite it in Ruby. Probably more work initially, but less headache on long term.

Comment: One more (rather bizarre idea), which could work, would be to use JRuby together with Jython, hence running everything on a Java Platform.

Comment: Another option, would be to shell out and run the cookiecutter cli.